# redirecting users to new subdomain using wildcard

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

i use to have my blog on my www subdomain but i recently shifted it to blog subdomain and www subdomain is now just a static website hosted on firebase

now i want to redirect my user from www post url  to new blog subdomain url

example: 
old url:
https://www.mywebsite/2017/a-valid-blog-post.html
new url:
https://blog.mywebsite/2017/a-valid-blog-post.html

i want to redirect user from old url to new url

i already tried this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture_url_segments_for_redirects
but for some reason it is not working

```
  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "/2017/:post*",  
    "destination": "https://blog.myapp.com/2017/:post",
    "type": 301
  } ]
```

i want all request which are sent to www subdomain & /2017 directory they should be redirected to blog subdomain with url

currently it is giving me  404 not found error

figured it out myself 
capture_url_segments_for_redirects dosent want in local hosting
i was hosting the project locally for testing & thats why it was not working
its weird because all other redirection were working , including with wildcard :)

Answer (score 0):

for all those who encounter this 
just deploy your project on firebase 
capturing url segments dosent work i local environment